# What is wrong with my mint plant?

Tags: diagnosis, mint

[image: mint]

I planted a new mint plant in a pot about a month ago and it had big, healthy green leaves. Now it has some serious issues but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I was watering it every 2-3 days and it was getting a full 8-10 hours of sunlight and the leaves slowly started to dull and shrink. I thought I was overwatering it and backed off and saw no change. It was just planted in the pot so I don't think it's root bound. What can I do?

Comment: Is this a mint plant?  Can you squeeze a leaf and smell mint?  What kind of mind do your think you purchased?  This looks like lamium the leaves are normal for lamium.https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3627/3498037519_92a3cfc0cf_b.jpg  Different variety perhaps.  Do you smell mint?  Is this 'frosted chocolate mint'?

Comment: Can it be sunburn? Or is it mildew? That are most often the reasons for [bleaching leaves](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/leaves-garden-plants-turning-white-dying-104893.html).

Comment: Examine beneath the leaves - this looks like spider mite infestation. You might need a magnifying glass...

Comment: It is definitely mint. It still has a strong smell. Kentucky Colonel Mint.

It was next to some rosemary which did have powdery mildew but I'm the leaves aren't really dusty (there's nothing to wipe off). They are just dull grey-green-brown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed it was thrips. Small long bugs on the undersides of the leaves were bleaching them.

Comment: Hi hollingswood! Thanks for posting this! We always appreciate it when someone returns and answers their own question. I hope you were able to treat them and save the plant! I know it's been a while a few months, but if you want to add what method you used to treat them, that would be helpful too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

with mint, make sure you plant it in a pot, or it will take over your garden. You can just find a mint plant somewhere and pull up a piece and stick it in a pot. Very easy to grow.